# Java servlet (tomcat) track multiple jdbc connections to multiple databases

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jdbc

I'm building a web app using Tomcat 7 that will give team members direct access to any number of databases (could be of any type. MySQL, Oracle, etc).

The number of possible databases could be in the dozens and their connection details are stored within the apps own database.

I'm looking for an approach for handling connections and connection pools. I can't decide how to handle opening and closing of connections. I know I don't want to open a connection for each request or each session. I had thought of creating a global hash map to store currently open connection pools and create a process for expiring ones that are not being used.

Does anything exist to do this? I can't help but feel like I'm reinventing the wheel. Tomcats Connection Pool can only handle one database at a time right?

Comment: You will need a `DataSource` for each database. For connection pools, you can use BoneCP or C3P0, among others.

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate the Tomcat's Connection Pool in your servlet.

It should look like this:

```
public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet {

  private DataSource ds;

  public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties prop;
    prop = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties();
    prop.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foo");
    prop.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    prop.setUsername("user");
    prop.setPassword("password");

    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dataSource;
    dataSource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
    dataSource.setPoolProperties(prop);

    ds = dataSource;
  }

  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    ...
  }
```

Please refer to the following document for details:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Plain_Ol'_Java